# Join para 2 tabelas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço para usar o metodo Join para dar um include de um valor de outra tabela? Neste caso eu ia usar a tabela ChamadaMusicas e a tabela MusicaVotadas

```
var chamadaMusicas = db.ChamadaMusicas
                       .Include(c => c.Chamada)
                       .Include(c => c.Musica)
                       .Where(c => c.Chamada.PessoaID.Equals(id)).Where(i => i.Chamada.Ativa.Equals(true))
                       .Join(db.MusicaVotadas)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: Qual é o problema?

Comment: Esse join não funciona. Da um erro quando eu uso esse join. Então devo estar usando de maneira errada.

Comment: Posta o erro. Um desenho mostrando o relacionamento entre as classes irá ajudar no entendimento do problema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No caso o seu join está escrito de forma errada.
Segue abaixo como seria +- a forma correta, a depender de como estão suas entidades:

```
var chamadaMusicas = db.ChamadaMusicas
   .Include(c => c.Chamada)
   .Include(c => c.Musica)
   .Where(c => c.Chamada.PessoaID.Equals(id)).Where(i => i.Chamada.Ativa.Equals(true))
   .Join(db.MusicaVotadas,
        ChamadaMusicas => ID, //Informa a PK (primeira parte da clausula on do sql)
        MusicaVotadas => ChamadaMusicasID //Informa a FK(segunda parte da clausula on do sql)
        (ChamadaMusicas, MusicaVotadas) = > new {ChamadaMusicas = ChamadaMusicas, MusicaVotadas = MusicaVotadas}// novo objeto formado pelo join
   ).ToList();
```

Segue também um link explicando como funciona o join

http://theburningmonk.com/2010/02/linq-lambda-expression-vs-query-expression/